# Create dictionary value field with predefined datatypes

Tags: python, dictionary

The defaultdict tool is a container in the collections class of Python. It's similar to the usual dictionary (dict) container, but the only difference is that a defaultdict will have a default value if that key has not been set yet. If you didn't use a defaultdict you'd have to check to see if that key exists, and if it doesn't, set it to what you want.
In this challenge, you will be given 2 integers ,n  and m. There are n  words, which might repeat, in word group A. There are m words belonging to word group B. For each m words, check whether the word has appeared in group A or not. Print the indices of each occurrence of m in group A. If it does not appear, print -1.

Comment: what is your specific question??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't ask questions to solve your assignments without trying anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
wordsA = ["hello", "world", "stackoverflow", "hello"]
wordsB = ["world", "hello", "notfound"]
dictA = {}  # create a dictionary
for i in range(len(wordsA)):
    if wordsA[i] in dictA:
        dictA[wordsA[i]].append(i)
    else:
        dictA[wordsA[i]] = [i]
for w in wordsB:
    if w in dictA:
        print(dictA[w])
    else:
        print(-1)
```